How to write a automated script that runs in background, and allows the user to do other task
I want to write a powershell script that does the following task
User/Group policies
Search ""Computer Management' -> Users and Groups , Administrators-> double click on Administartors > save as txt
Autoplay

Control Panel > All Control Panel Items AutoPlay -> save as txt

USB port

click winlogo + S -> type "regedit" -> go to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR -> take screenshot

Clock sync

Search ""Settings"" -> Date and Time -> Change Date and Time -> save as txt
Search ""Settings"" -> Date and Time -> Click on the Time Zone drop down -> save as txt

Capture USB port registry settings
function Get-USBPortSettings {
$usbSettings = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR'
$usbSettings | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\USBPortSettings.txt"
}
for the rest of the question I am not been able to find any commands that work
